# Ignore duplicates options in argparse

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'm using the `choices` argument in argparse.
If I run `-h` I get the choices two times, once for `-a` and once for `--argument`. As I have around 30 options with long names the help text is quite cluttered. Can I only get it once? (without removing one of the flags).
Output from help:

```
$ python3 test.py  -h
usage: test.py [-h] [-a {Option1,Option2}]

optional arguments:
   -h, --help            show this help message and exit
   -a {Option1,Option2}, --argument {Option1,Option2}
                    Help.
```

Minimal example:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', '--argument', help='Help.', choices=['Option1', 'Option2'])

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Experiment with the `metavar` parameter.

Comment: You could also omit the `--argument`, and optionally set `dest='argument'`.  `help` is set up to show your users all the ways they could provide the values.  A long list of `choices` is problem for any machine generated help.